# Multiple registration form according to different roles

Tags: wordpress, plugins, roles

I am trying to make the different registration forms according to roles. Like I have 3 roles -> trainers, partner, team. I want to signup all the users with these different-2 forms and need to assign the roles automatically in backend. So, for that I am using the Ultimate member plugin but when I try to register the account with the different forms it always assign the recent created role to the new user. Can anyone please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: I don't get your question. What are you trying to do? Can't you put a drop-down or something in a single form to select the roles?

Comment: @MurshidAhmed thanks for your response. Well I am trying to assign the roles to the different forms from the backend. And for that I will share the register sign up link to the users and users will signup from that links and the roles will automatically assign to that user according to the form. Are you getting my point?

Answer (score 0):

Going through the mentioned plugin's [documentation for adding a form](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/87-adding-a-registration-form) it says there is an option to **Assign role to form**. Check the image of customing the form widget below

[image: customing the form widget of Ultimate Membership plugin]

So basically you have to create 3 forms.

- Assign the different roles to each form.
- Get the shortcode of each form
- Create 3 different pages
- Paste the shortcode of each form in the respective pages
- Share the link to the particular page depends on your need.

Comment: thanks for your message. Yes, I have already made the different forms and assigned the roles according to that but it's not working properly. Suppose I have made the 3 roles and try to register the account with any of the form. So, after that the last created role will automatically assign to the new user. It's not working according to the form assigned role.